# A Question on Flatness of Complete Local Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness, formal-completions

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a morphism of finitely-generated $k$-algebras. Assume that $f$ is flat, and that $\mathfrak{p}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ are the corresponding prime ideals. Then we have a flat local ring map $g\colon A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{q}}$, since this is the composition of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ with $B_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{q}}$. The first is flat via base change, since $B_{\mathfrak{p}}=B\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the second is a localization.

Let $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{q}}$ be the corredponding maximal ideals.
We moreover assume that $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}B_{\mathfrak{q}}=\hat{\mathfrak{q}}$, and that the residue fields of the two local rings are isomorphic. This implies the following:

1. The local ring map of the completions
   $\hat{g}\colon \hat{A}_{\mathfrak{p}}\to  \hat{B}_{\mathfrak{q}} 
   $ is also a flat ring map.
2. We have isomorphism $\hat{B}_{\mathfrak{q}} \cong \hat{A}_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}  B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ .

Here is my question.
Now assume that $f\colon Spec(B)\to Spec(A); \mathfrak{q}\mapsto \mathfrak{p}$ is etale, then it forces $\hat{g}$ to be an isomorphism. Meanwhile, since $B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is a flat $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module, it's free. Say $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}^{\oplus n}$. Then we have
$$
\hat{B}_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong \hat{A}_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}  B_{\mathfrak{q}} \cong \hat{A}_{\mathfrak{p}}^{\oplus n}
$$
This forces $n=1$ and $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which I believe is not true for etale morphisms.

Can anyone help me figuring out where I messed up in the above argument ?

Edit:
I think the problem might be that, $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$-module via $g$ doesnot imply that $g$ is a ring isomorphism. But I cannot think of an example.

Comment: So your question can be rephrased as follows: let $f$ be a flat unramified map $A \rightarrow B$ of local noetherian rings, (where $A$ and $B$ are essentially of finite type over a field that $f$ preserves), then is the max-adic completion of $f$ flat. Right?

Comment: @Aphelli Yes, that's correct. Let me briefly explain the reason for asking this question. I am preparing my lecture notes for next class of etale morphisms following Mumford's Red Book, and I want to prove that flat+unramified implies (standard) etale via showing that flat + unramified implies isomorphism on the completions of local rings. If I can prove that such completion is flat, then over local ring it's necessarily free. Then I can follow the standard differential construction to prove that it's also a quotient map, hence has to be isomorphism.

Comment: By flatness and unramifiedness, $\hat{B}$ is isomorphic to $B \otimes_A \hat{A}$.

Comment: @Aphelli Is there a reference or a skechy explanation for this result? I am thinking the following. Since $B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is flat over the local ring $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, then it is free, i.e.,  $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}^n$. Then if $\hat{B}=B\otimes \hat{A}$, this gives $\hat{B}_{\mathfrak{q}}=\hat{A}^n_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Thus if $f$ is etale this forces $n=1$, and hence $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}$. But this is not always true for etale maps. Is there something I messed up in above arugment ?

Comment: Since $B$ is flat over $A$, $-\otimes B$ commutes with limits (I think? or maybe it is *finite* limits and the argument breaks down…). Anyway, in your reasoning, $f$ being étale doesn’t force $n=1$, look at the case of a finite separable field extension.

Comment: @Aphelli I think I should add that the residue fields of the local rings are isomorphic, otherwise as your example, finite separable field example would certainly be a counter example. In which case, etale morphism forces the completions to be isomorphic, thus $n=1$?

Comment: Yes, in this case $n=1$ and it follows by faithful flatness that the original local rings were equal… so it’s not good and I need to think again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s slightly redefine the setting: $A$ and $B$ are noetherian local algebras essentially of finite type over a base field $k$, and we have a local étale $k$-morphism $A \rightarrow B$. Let us call $m$ the maximal ideal of $A$, and $\hat{-}$ is the $m$-adic completion. We want to prove that $\hat{B}$ is flat over $\hat{A}$.

Since $B$ is unramified over $A$, the residue field extension is finite. We can thus find $b_1,\ldots,b_n \in B$ such that they form a basis of $B/m$ over $A/m$. In particular, for every $t \geq 0$, $B/m^t$ is flat over $A/m^t$ thus free, and by the above it is free of rank $n$.

Consider the morphism $\psi: A^n \rightarrow B$ mapping $e_i$ to $b_i$. By assumption, if $P=\psi(A^n)$, then $B=mB+P$. By induction, for every $t \geq 1$, $B=m^tB+P$, so that $\psi \otimes A/m^t$ is a surjection of free modules of same rank over a local ring, so it is an isomorphism. Thus the map $\hat{A}^n \rightarrow \hat{B}$ sending the $i$-th basis element to $b_i$ is an isomorphism. So $\hat{B}$ is free, hence flat, over $\hat{A}$.